# Matlab CODE of ADER scheme

Tags: finite-volume

I read  ADER WENO Finite Volume scheme for hyperbolic conservation laws with source term. I want to implement this method in Matlab coding. I got some problems in coding during to computation of 
numerical flux. Please help me the Matlab coding
$$u_t+f(u)_x=S(u,x,t),\; u(0,x)=u_0(x),\; x\in \mathbb{R}, \;t>0,\;u(t,-\infty)=u(t,\infty)=0.$$

Comment: Could you please specify which kind of ADER scheme you would like to implement, possibly a paper or other resource? The problem to solve along with the boundary conditions would also help a lot. Your current code or MWE can also help

Comment: u_t+f(u,x)_x=s(u,t,x); u(x,0)=u_0(x) solved by ADER finite volume scheme

Comment: Please edit the question with the equation in the comment (use the Latex style syntax). Also you should add more info, as Rover asked, and add the problem that you found during the coding.

Comment: Hi Mauro Vanzetto and  Rover I am rewriting the same question with math mode $$u_t+f(u,x)_x=s(u,t,x);\quad u(x,0)=u_0(x), \ x\in [a, b],\; t>0, \;u(a,t)=0, \; u(b,t)=0$$

Comment: What is the problem that you found during the coding? What did you already try? Without this informations people have got difficulties to suggest a solution.
(P.s. in stack exchange to send a notification of a comment to a person use @NameOfUser)